# Octopress - dealing with sub-directory folder structure for pages

Tags: octopress

Is it possible to have a subdirectory for all my pages?

Currently:

```
rake new_page['siht-daer-uoy-nac']
```

generates the markdown files like so:

```
source/
   |_ _posts
   |_ <some-other-directories> 
   |_ siht-daer-uoy-nac
                       |_ index.markdown
```

then doing a

```
 rake generate
```

takes care of everything and spurts out a pretty html file.

My problem/question:

Call me OCD afflicted, but i would like to have a directory structure like so:

```
source/
   |_ _posts
   |_ <some-other-directories> 
   |_ _pages
            |_ siht-daer-uoy-nac
                                |_ index.markdown
```

Having my top directory structure littered with a bunch of page slugs, makes me cry a little inside. I understand jekyll is merely a static page generator and plays its part only upto the point of html generation (and deployment).

### Is it possible to maintain this kind of a folder structure for my pages?

Update:

I don't think it's possible out of the box to have a _pages directory without significantly messing around with octopress/jekyll source code (one of these days). In the meantime, a workaround to have a bunch of similar page like posts grouped is as ngm suggested below:

```
 rake new_page["osx-essential-software/2011.markdown"]
 # creates /source/osx-essential-software/2011/index.markdown
 rake new_page["osx-essential-software/2010.markdown"]
 # creates /source/osx-essential-software/2010/index.markdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's by design or by accident, but if you do:

```
rake new_page["foo/nac-i-sey"]
```

you'll get a page for `nac-i-sey` under a `foo` subdirectory.

So if you wanted another page under `foo`, you could do:

```
rake new_page["foo/another-page"]
```

Comment: I asked this question sometime back and found out how to go about it. But you get extra brownie points for providing the solution and being able to read my question :D. Updated my question with some possible strategies to achieve what i asked.